# Как в react router получить контент страницы или из div

Tags: reactjs, react-router

в данном примере при переходе по ссылкам происходит рендеринг компанентов
***Home*** и ***News***

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import createClass from 'create-react-class'

import {BrowserRouter as Router ,Route ,Link ,browserHistory ,Switch} from 'react-router-dom'

// Pages
const Home = () => (
    <div>
        <h1>Welcome to  Home page !</h1>
    </div>
);

const News = () => (
  <div>
      <h1>this page News !</h1>
  </div>
);





// config Route 
const Main = () => (
    <main>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
            <Route path='/news' component={News}/>
        </Switch>
    </main>
);

const Header = () => (
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to='/news'>News</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
);




// render
const App = () => (
    <div>
        <Header />
        <Main />
    </div>
);
ReactDOM.render((
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

но у меня на этом сайте уже есть эти страницы ,
как сделать что бы происходил рендеринг ни компонентов а страниц ?

Как при обычном поведении ссылок только без **перезагрузки** !

то есть я удаляю этот код

```
// Pages
const Home = () => (
    //<div>
        //<h1>Welcome to  Home page !</h1>
    //</div>
);

const News = () => (
  //<div>
      //<h1>this page News !</h1>
  //</div>
);
```

Comment: Думаю что без перезагрузки никак. Либо страницы переделывать в виде реакт-компонентов.

Comment: видимо да , нужен подход API